# Why does `nix-shell` fail with missing `test-suite` dependencies when I only ask for a `library` of `haskellPackages`?

Tags: haskell, cabal, nix

Might anyone of you know why

```
$ nix-shell \
  -I nixpkgs=https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs-channels/archive/nixos-unstable.tar.gz \
  -p "haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages (p: [p.compose-ltr])" \
  --run ghci
```

fails with

```
Configuring compose-ltr-0.2.3...

Setup: Encountered missing dependencies:
QuickCheck ==2.8.1, hspec ==2.2.0

builder for ‘/nix/store/pvmm9qcp9xpj5hw77nbfyfj4wxs49jl8-compose-ltr-0.2.3.drv’ failed with exit code 1
cannot build derivation ‘/nix/store/41znxh9qi408n9j63fqvixrlkaasrgkx-ghc-8.0.1-with-packages.drv’: 1 dependencies couldn't be built
```

?

(blank lines added for separation and emphasis)

I'm asking since as far as I am aware I'm not asking `nix` to build/run unit tests of `compose-ltr`, so why does it care about `QuickCheck` and `hspec`?

Yes, QuickCheck and hspec are mentioned [in the `.cabal` file, but only for `test-suite spec` and not `library`](https://github.com/Wizek/compose-ltr/blob/master/compose-ltr.cabal#L32).

---

Additionally, can I fix this either by

1. specifying something further in my `nix-shell` command,
2. changing something in the `.cabal` file of `compose-ltr`, or
3. adding a `.nix` file to `compose-ltr`?

I wouldn't say I have much experience with `nix` yet, so a detailed response is welcome.

Comment: Confirmed on my machine. I *think* that this is the kind of things that should be reported as bugs on https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues instead of being posted here on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
p.compose-ltr
```

with

```
(haskell.lib.dontCheck p.compose-ltr)
```

which disables tests for this package. Overall this should be included into https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/configuration-common.nix (a PR on GitHub will be welcome, I think)